# Linq To Sql Skip Take

Tags: c#, linq

I want to save each icon path into a variable, from the query bellow , only PathIcon1 has value . The remain path icon are empty

Query

```
using (CarteringServiceClientDataContext dc = new CarteringServiceClientDataContext())
            {


                result = (from a in dc.GetTable<tblSupplier>()
                          join b in dc.GetTable<tblCity>()
                          on a.CityId equals b.Id
                          join c in dc.GetTable<tblZone>()
                          on b.ZoneId equals c.Id

                          let r = (from re in dc.GetTable<tblClientReview>()
                                   where re.SupplierId == a.Id
                                   select re.note).Average()

                          let i = (from im in dc.GetTable<tblSupplierItem>()
                                   where im.SupplierId == a.Id
                                   select im.tblItem.IconPath).ToArray()

                          select new SearchResult
                          {
                              CompanyId = a.Id,
                              CompanyName = a.Company,
                              Localisation = a.Locality,
                              City = b.Name,
                              Zone = c.Name,
                              Rating = r.ToString(),
                              PathIcon1 = i.Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                              PathIcon2 = i.Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                              PathIcon3 = i.Skip(2).Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                              PathIcon4 = i.Skip(3).Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                              PathIcon5 = i.Skip(4).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()
                          }).ToList<SearchResult>();


            }
```

A part from PathIcon1, the remaing PathIcon are null

Comment: Maybe your backing data doesn't have the information you're looking for?  `.SingleOrDefault()` will quietly return an empty value if none is found.  When you debug this, what's in `i`?

Comment: @David a list of string , more than 10 items

Comment: let i = (from im in dc.GetTable<tblSupplierItem>()
           where im.SupplierId == a.Id
           select im.tblItem.IconPath).ToArray().Add("Test") are you try like this and control PathIcon2 value?@Jmocke

Comment: @AlperTungaArslan sorry , i dont get your suggestion

Comment: @Jmocke  actually i think i.count() ==1 So If you add "test" as string in i and you try to code you see PathIcon2  value will "test"

Answer (score 1):

```
using (CarteringServiceClientDataContext dc = new CarteringServiceClientDataContext())
                {  
                    result = (from a in dc.GetTable<tblSupplier>()
                              join b in dc.GetTable<tblCity>()
                              on a.CityId equals b.Id
                              join c in dc.GetTable<tblZone>()
                              on b.ZoneId equals c.Id

                              let r = (from re in dc.GetTable<tblClientReview>()
                                       where re.SupplierId == a.Id
                                       select re.note).Average()

                              let i = (from im in dc.GetTable<tblSupplierItem>()
                                       where im.SupplierId == a.Id
                                       select im.tblItem.IconPath).ToArray().Add("test")

                              select new SearchResult
                              {
                                  CompanyId = a.Id,
                                  CompanyName = a.Company,
                                  Localisation = a.Locality,
                                  City = b.Name,
                                  Zone = c.Name,
                                  Rating = r.ToString(),
                                  PathIcon1 = i.Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                                  PathIcon2 = i.Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                                  PathIcon3 = i.Skip(2).Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                                  PathIcon4 = i.Skip(3).Take(1).SingleOrDefault(),
                                  PathIcon5 = i.Skip(4).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()
                              }).ToList<SearchResult>();
          }
```

Try this if you are get  PathIcon2 value as "test" your problem isn't skip or take. Just i list includes one item. Adn I think so.